# How to apply a relational operator on a cell in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I would like to know the **number of values that are less than 0.0038** in a **cell** of 41 X 41 double.

For example, I have the cell below:

```
B = num2cell(rand(41));
```

When I applied such condition `sum(A(:) < 0.0038)`, it gave me an error, which is `Operator '<' is not supported for operands of type 'cell'`.

So, do I need to convert the cell to a matrix and apply the operation? **Or** is there any specific way to use this condition on the cell directly?

Comment: Try `A{:}` perhaps?

Comment: If all of the values in your cell array are scalars, why are you using cell arrays?

Comment: @beaker sorry, I did not deal with cell before.

Comment: @SH_IQ I'm not sure I understand your response. My question was, if your data is a 41x41 double array, why are you adding the complexity of storing it in a cell array rather than a normal matrix?

Comment: @beaker I receive ready-created data stored in a cell, and I wanted to apply on it the operation.

Comment: So convert the cell array to a matrix and avoid all of the problems you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote, one way would be to convert `B` back to a numeric array. The other way, i.e. using the condition directly on the cell array, is possible with the `cellfun` function:

```
isSmaller = cellfun( @(X) X < 0.0038, B(:), 'UniformOutput', true )
numSmaller = sum(isSmaller)
```

**Explanation:**

- `cellfun` applies the anonymous function  `@(X) X < 0.0038` on all cells of `B`.
- It stores the results in the array `isSmaller`.
- `'UniformOutput', true` triggers that `isSmaller` is a numeric array. To store the results in a cell array you could use `'UniformOutput', false`.

**Remark:**
As beaker commented, in your example it is not necessary to convert `randn(41)` to a cell array in the first place. You could store it as a numeric array and apply the condition directly on the array. However, I assume that your example is meant as minimum working example (MWE).

Comment: @ I really appreciate your answer, but it did not work. It asked me first to change 'UniformOutput' to false and when I changed it, I faced this error (Invalid data type. First argument must be numeric or logical.) because my size data type is double.

Comment: Ok, then your input is not the the cell array given in your question, or?

Comment: I specified above a cell of 41 X 41 double.

Comment: With ```B = num2cell(rand(41));```, my answer works perfectly. Which MATLAB version are you using?

Comment: 2022b, yes it works perfectly dear sir, but what if the data type is double? cell with a double data type.

Comment: The data type in the cell is actually ```double```,  ```randn``` return doubles. Please try ```class( randn(41))```.

Comment: @SH_IQ If this does not work for you, I suspect your cell array might contain other things besides double arrays. A cell array can have a different type of array for each element. You might need to extract the row or column that contains the doubles, using normal indexing: `B(:,3)` for example.

Comment: Note that cellfun is very slow and a plain for loop is usually faster.

Answer (score 1):

A few alternatives to the `cellfun` approach if your data is in a `cell`.

```
s = sum(B{:}(:));      % works if B is a cell with a single element
s = sum(B{1,4}(:));    % works if B is a cell with several elements 
                       % and you want the sum of the one in {1, 4}
```